# using protobuf-net with decoupled interfaces

Tags: protobuf-net

I am trying to use Protobuf.net version 2.0.0.668 for file storage.  My solution has interfaces defined in one project and classes defined in separate projects, with references from class projects to the interface project.  Each class uses an interface to refer to other classes.  This has worked fine until now - but protobuf wants the interfaces to specify the concrete class types in a ProtoInclude attribute.  This is impossible given my project structure.

There should be a way around this.  For example, I use a service locator design pattern to return class instances for interface references when needed by unrelated classes:  IServiceLocator<>.GetInstance().  Is there some way to do this in protobuf - have it ask for an object of type "T" when it needs one?

Or is there another solutions short of reorganizing my project into one massive entity?

Answer (score 0):

No one has stepped up to answer, and I haven't found a way to do this myself, so I have abandoned this approach (using ProtoInclude and related attributes).  ProtoInclude inverts the dependency relationship between an interface and its implementation which limits its usefulness in some contexts.  My solution is to do it all by hand: write my own .proto files etc.  Which is not too bad, overall.